# Make all KPI Status Icons in diamond shape

Tags: 2007, custom

KPIs in sharepoint by default have danger Kpi as Red diamonds, warning as yellow traingles and on track as green circles. Also we have flat, checkmarks, traffic lights status icons. What i want to do is make all three indicators - green, yellow and red in diamond shape.

My KPIs have both lists and excel spreadsheets as their data source.
Also upon changing the status icon to diamond i would like to see it reflect in the KPI Details web part and not only in the KPI List.

Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that colorblinds won't appreciate all similar icons with only differences in color.

Comment: thanks for that ill put this argument across in favour of retaining defualt kpis :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, I have created a technique that allows to display any kind of indicator (or generally speaking any HTML) in SharePoint lists. You can find some examples here:

[Path to SharePoint - Color coding: more examples](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/12/09/color-coding-more-examples/)

[Path to SharePoint - HTML Calculated Column and Unicode Graphics](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/01/04/html-calculated-column-and-unicode-graphics/)

It may not be the right approach for large scale deployments, but works pretty well if you are just targeting a couple lists, or don't have server access.

Comment: Thanks for the info Christophe but you see few of my kpis are from excel , and also when i display this in a kpi details web part i dont think the calculated coulmn solution would work out. If im wrong please feel free to correct me

Comment: If you use this technique, you just rely on a standard view with the appropriate filters to display the details.

Answer (score 3):

I thought about replacing this indicators for my own long time ago, they must be somewhere as  images in directory structure, but since we have [Pentalogic Highligher](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/highlighter) installed, I do not worry about anything. (Task lists, ToDo, Priority and blank rows highlighting, countdown, or progress bars, that made all our users via scripts.) All this small little things make lists more user friendly and clear. Yes, it is not free, but definitely working.

Comment: Thanks for the info Molik , cant use paid add ons but will def keep this in mind for future requirements :)

Comment: +1 I can vouch for Highlighter; especially since its our product. ;)

Comment: @AabidAli yes, it took a while before they approved it for me, but when migration fails twice because of nonstandard things and scrips everywhere (mainly for progress bars), the opinion was changed. You can forget about that little customizations in the future or someone else can come

Comment: @StuartPegg so, thank you :o) Highlighter and Data Synchronization studio make my life easier every day :o)

Comment: @Molik true, thats when they all learn :). Also Thanks for introducing me to pentalogic , i think some of their other products like pivot cahrts and tables could be really useful to me when we move on from only oob.

Comment: @StuartPegg Good job on those webparts :)

Comment: @Molik: :) Glad to hear it's useful to you.

Comment: @AAbidAli: Thanks, I'll pass your comments on to the rest of the team. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any luck using the native KPI functionality, you may want to look at some alternatives. After working on Highlighter, I wrote an article on our company blog about the various ways of achieving this:

[How to create a SharePoint KPI column](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-kpi-column/)

Free:

- Javascript: Do the work on the client-side *(as pioneered and mentioned by @Christophe)*
- Designer: Customise the list view using SharePoint Designer
- Download: Download an open source Custom Field Type
- Code: Create a custom field type from scratch

Not free:

- Enterprise Edition: Use the Out of The Box Enterprise Edition functionality *(probably not a useful recommendation in this instance)*
- Buy: Buy a pre-made Custom Field Type *(I think you can guess which I recommend ;) )*

Links and more information on each of these options can be found in the article.